# Mathematical Physics: Differential equation of a raindrop

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I hope this is a suited question for this site since it contains a mix of physics and mathematics. In case I should post this on the physics stackexchange site, please let me know.

> A spherical raindrop is falling from the sky. Because of the humid
>   atmosphere the raindrop will gain mass during his fall. The increase
>   in mass per time is proportional to the current surface area.
>
> 1. Find an equation for the radius of the drop as a function of time ($r(t)$). ($r(0) =r_0$)
> 2. Find and solve the equation of motion for the raindrop. The equation of motion should depend on $r_0$

**My work so far:**

Mass: $m(t)=\frac{4}{3} \pi r(t)^3 \rho $

Sufrace Area: $A(t)=4\pi r(t)^2$

$$\begin{aligned}      
       & \implies \frac{dm(t)}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{4}{3}\pi r(t)^3 \rho)=4 \pi r(t)^2 r'(t)\rho\\
       & \iff 4 \pi \rho r(t)^2 r'(t)=\lambda 4 \pi r(t) ^2 \iff r'(t)=\frac{\lambda}{\rho} \iff      \frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{\lambda}{\rho} \\
       & \iff \int dr = \frac{\lambda}{\rho} \int dt \iff r(t)=\frac{\lambda}{\rho}t+c \\
& \color{blue}{\implies r(t)=\alpha t+r_0} \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \text{where}\space \space\alpha=\frac{\lambda}{\rho}
     \end{aligned}$$

Equation of motion:

Gravitational Force: $mg$

Air Friction: $kv(t)$

$$\begin{aligned} &F=mg-kv \iff \frac{d}{dt}(mv)=m'v+v'm=mg-kv \\ & \end{aligned}$$

I tried substituting $m'$ and $m$ into my equation and I am left with:

$$\begin{aligned}& mv'+\frac{3m \alpha}{r}=mg-kv\end{aligned}$$

I tried solving this in wolfram alpha and I get the following result: [LINK](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mx%27%27%28t%29%2B%283*m*alpha%29%28alpha%20t%2Bc%29%3Dmg-kx%27%28t%29)

It looks super messy and I don't think that is the solution I am supposed to get. Am I doing something wrong? Is there some substitution I can make to make it easier to solve?

Comment: I just recently ran across this: https://www.physics.harvard.edu/uploads/files/undergrad/probweek/prob5.pdf  and solution: https://www.physics.harvard.edu/uploads/files/undergrad/probweek/sol5.pdf  Not sure if it helps though.

Comment: The first part is correct as $ \frac {dm}{dr} = k A $. Is the resistance proportional to velocity or its square?

Comment: @Narasimham It isn't specified in the question. I should have problably used "newtonian friction" $=kv^2$ and not "stokes friction" $=kv$.

Comment: You can simplify your life a bit by just noting the following about your model and what you have already solved about it: $r$ is linear in time with a positive slope, $m$ is proportional to $r^3$ with a positive slope, $F$ is proportional to $m$ (and hence $r^3$) with a positive slope and proportional to $v$ with a negative slope. So $r=c_1t+c_2$, $m=c_3r^3$, $F=c_4r^3-c_5v=mv'+m'v=c_3r^3v'+3c_3r^2r'v$. (Written this way, all constants are positive.)

Comment: Plugging everything in you get a first order linear equation with non-constant coefficients for $v$, namely $c_4r^3-c_5v=c_3r^3v'+3c_3r^2r'v=c_3r^3v'+c_6r^2v$ (this equation defines $c_6$). This can be solved by the method of integrating factors.

Comment: @Ian Bingo! Thats a cool way to look at it/solve it. I will try doing that. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see something important that I missed: your friction should scale up with surface area. For instance if it is proportional to area, then the equation becomes $c_4 r^3 - c_7 r^2 v = c_3 r^3 v' + c_6 r^2 v$, which is now much nicer, since you can cancel out two factors of $r$ across the board.

Comment: Your last line still has $m$ in it.  Since $m$ is a function of $r(t)$, and you already know $r(t)$, you know $m(t)$.  Make that substitution into your DE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume additionally that the friction is proportional to surface area and to velocity, then you can run the following logic to get a pretty simple ODE for $v$:

\begin{align}
r & =c_1t + c_2 \\
m & =c_3 r^3 \\
F & =c_4 m - c_5 r^2 v = c_6 r^3 - c_5 r^2 v \\
F & =m'v+mv' \\
& = 3c_3 r^2 r' v + c_3r^3 v' \\
& = 3c_3 c_1 r^2 v + c_3 r^3 v' \\
& = c_6 r^3 - c_5 r^2 v \\
& \Rightarrow 3 c_3 c_1 v + c_3 r v' = c_6 r - c_5 v.
\end{align}

In normal form for first order linear ODEs:

$$v' + \frac{3 c_3 c_1 + c_5}{c_3 r} v = \frac{c_6}{c_3}.$$

Actually plugging in what all these constants are in your notation:

$$v'+\frac{4 \pi \rho \alpha + k}{\frac{4}{3} \pi \rho (\alpha t + r_0)} v = g.$$

This is quite tractable using the method of integrating factors.

Comment: Thank you! I used variation of parameters but I guess that also works.

Comment: @qmd The two methods are essentially equivalent. :)